# NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest not working

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am now working on a small app where I need to make connections to some web sites in order to get some information.

Here is the function I made, which satisfies my needs 90% of the time.

```
func requestFunctionOn(url: String) {
    print(#function + " url: \(url)")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request,
                                                     completionHandler: {
                                                        data, response, error in

                                                        if error != nil {
                                                            print("error=\(error)")
                                                            return
                                                        }

                                                        print("RSC = \((response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode)")
                                                        ............. doing some more useful work .............
                                                     }).resume()
}
```

There are times though where I hit a problem, without me knowing why. For example below are traces in the debugger console of a working case (RSC = 200) and of a non working case (RSC = 404):

Working as expected:

```
requestFunctionOn url: http://abcnews.go.com
RSC = 200
(lldb)
```

Not working as expected:

```
requestFunctionOn url: http://www.bloomberg.com/asia
RSC = 404
(lldb)
```

What can I do to make the second case work? Where do I need to look at?

Comment: Are you trying to post or get? Try `request.HTTPMethod = "GET"`

Comment: I am trying to get the contents of the web site in order to parse it and read what I need. As I mentioned this mostly works. In the first case mentioned I can do it.

Comment: @ Leo Dabus: Following your idea, I just made a few tests. Here are the result:

When using : request.HTTPMethod = "POST"; I have the effects mentioned in my post.

When using : request.HTTPMethod = "GET"; it works. When simply removing the line it also works.

I don't quite understand what is going on. Maybe you can explain?

Thanks for the tip in any case.

Comment: If you don't specify HTTPMethod Ithe default value (get) is used. Post it is only used to send data to the api

Comment: BTW you don't need to use a request, you can use dataTaskWithURL

Comment: That sounds interesting. But how do I go to get what I was getting inside completionHandler: and do my useful work? As you can guess I am no expert in using NSURLSession, so forgive my basic questions.

Comment: Just start typing it and let Xcode automatically complete it for you. dataTaskWithURL has also an initializer with a completion handler

Comment: Yes I also just discovered that, thank you any way. You definitely gave me good hints.

Comment: NSURLSession won't let you send POST requests without providing a post body (which may be empty, but not nil) and a Content-Type header.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- You need to set the Content-Type header to indicate the contents of the POST request's body, with the Swift equivalent of this:

  ```
  [request addValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  ```
- You need to set the request body:

  ```
  request.HTTPBody = [NSData data];
  ```

Apologies for the Objective-C snippets, but I figure that should be close enough for you to be able to figure out the equivalent Swift code.  :-)